# Will card-io sdk read 13, 18 and 19 digit credit cards

Tags: ios, iphone, ocr, cardio

I am integrating card-io sdk in iPhone application. So Will card-io sdk read 13, 18 and 19 digit credit card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

card-io only supports :

1. Visa -like patterns, which consists of 16 digits.
2. American Express -like patterns, which consists of 15 digits.